# Packing the package failed (exit code 127) when pulling package from github

Tags: docker, yarnpkg, yarn-v2

I have a problem with the build on docker hub, when I build manually it builds fine, but when I trigger build on docker hub I get Packing the package failed (exit code 127).

I'm trying to pull package from github with yarn2

```
#17 130.1 ➤ YN0058: │ mui-datatables@https://github.com/luluhoc/mui-datatables.git#commit=b475f432b0720022eb1317b25119d0b76ca3424c: Packing the package failed (exit code 127, logs can be found here: /tmp/xfs-d5695126/pack.log)
```

Comment: Did you read the logfile `/tmp/xfs-d5695126/pack.log`?